# Dynamically adding TinyMCE editor to textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I am adding textboxes dynamically to a div. Something likhe this

```
$('#xyz').click(function()
{
     $(#myDiv).append('<textarea></textarea>');
});
```

Now I want to attach tinymce editor to these textareas, Can you help me in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#xyz').click(function() {
    var myTextarea = $("<textarea></textarea>");
    myTextarea.attr("id", "mce-editor");
    $("#myDiv").append(myTextarea);

    // this inistalises the TinyMCE editor upon the element with the id in the last parameter.
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "mce-editor");
});
```

Comment: @Rory- It worked upto one extent but it worked only for first textbox as soon as two ids ("mce-editor") it stopped working, how can I attache editors with dynamic ids?

Comment: Is ID depenedency neccessary? Isn't there a way to do the same via class instead of id?

Comment: using tinymce each editor instance needs to get a unique id!  You may use Math.random() to achieve this:  myTextarea.attr("id", Math.random());

Comment: no, tinymce wants an id, if you do not assign one "content" is used as default, but starting with the second editor instance you will need a second id different from the first. In your case you have to assign an id to the element you want to initalize the editor instance for onclick otherwise you would have no id to give to the function execCommand.

Answer (score 2):

You could even attach the tinymce element to the div directly, because you don't need a textarea in order to edit and submit text using a tinymce editor instance. Tinymce will create an editable iframe in the dom in which the user is able to edit html content. OnSave the editors content gets written back to the html element the tinymce editor was created for (this can be a textarea, a div, a paragraph or another html elment).

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'myDiv');
```